# Database not updating row

Tags: php, mysql

Before you assume I didn't establish a database connection, I did. the only portion of the code that does not update is the if empty statements.

All the values can be echoed out correctly, it's just that query doesn't work.

This is in directory config and named stuff.php

```
 $user = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
 $user_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'";
 $result = $mysqli->query($user_query);
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
 $referrer = $row['ref'];
 $refearn = $row['refearn'];
```

verify.php

```
include('config/stuff.php');
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {  // Get Real IP              
    $IP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; 
} else { 
    $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

if ($IP=="external server ip here") {
        if (!empty($referrer)){
            $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET points=points+10, refearn = refearn+10 WHERE username='".$referrer."'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
        }
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE users SET points=points+".$earnings.", completed = completed+1 WHERE username='".$subid."'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
}
```

Comment: do you get any error? or, could you try getting output of that query `"UPDATE users SET points=points+10, refearn = refearn+10 WHERE username='".$referrer."'"` and check that in phpmyadmin manually - if that work..

Comment: There's no error from what I can tell. I can confirm it works in PHPmyadmin, I'm working on echoing it out right now.

I'm having a brainfart right now, how can I echo out the query?

Comment: So it is updating your just trying to output the response?

Comment: If I manually type it out into PHPmyadmin, with the corresponding $referrer value, it works.

Comment: Did you check my answer? Is it still not working?

Comment: No it is not. I noticed I may have left out a big detail in my original post. I tried to reduce irrelevant code but it may help... Updating it now.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you could try to retrieve the value of points through a query then add to it so you're just updating to a simple value. However, if mysql_error() is returning an error, it should be easier to figure out.

Example:

```
$getPoints = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM table WHERE condition");
$points = mysql_result($getPoints, 0, "points");

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET points=" . ($points+10) . " WHERE condition");
```

Hope that helps. Another consideration, though. Why use an endif structure unless you're breaking PHP tags to display content?

Comment: I don't think it will make a different though...
My syntax is already correct so I don't understand why it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE `users` SET `points`=`points`+10, `refearn` = `refearn`+10 WHERE `username`='".$referrer."'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Hope this helps. What I think is, mysql query might be taking those as constant - not as the mysql rows. Try that